# Angular.json has two properties of script and styles

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I was trying adding styles and scripts to my angular.json file but both doesn't seem to work for some reason either bootstrap and others scripts doesn't take effect, later I figure out that there are 2 places to write script and style in angular.json see below

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-firebase": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular-firebase",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          ],
          "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"{
                "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
                "version": 1,
                "newProjectRoot": "projects",
                "projects": {
                  "angular-crud": {
                    "projectType": "application",
                    "schematics": {
                      "@schematics/angular:application": {
                        "strict": true
                      }
                    },
                    "root": "",
                    "sourceRoot": "src",
                    "prefix": "app",
                    "architect": {
                      "build": {
                        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                        "options": {
                          "outputPath": "dist/angular-crud",
                          "index": "src/index.html",
                          "main": "src/main.ts",
                          "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                          "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                          "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                          ],
                          "styles": [
                            "src/styles.css"
                          ],
                          "scripts": []    
                        },
                        "configurations": {
                          "production": {
```

My question is why we have 2 architect.build to insert styles and scripts in angular.json?

Answer (score 1):

Because some projects may require specific styles for specific environments or only in build or only in server and this way you can specify what you need, in what environment.

For example, I want to load google analytics in my production build only and not on the server at all so I include it in `"scripts"` of `"production"` configuration in `"build"` and not in the `"development"` configuration.